# Anybody have idea when will be moderate election

Tags: discussion

I have this question in my mind, its more than 2 years but no moderate election announced so far.

i saw, 1st one was in 2011 and 2nd in 2013 but no after that. anybody have the information on it.

Comment: Mods should recycle every 2 years or so, IMHO. Keeps the community fresh and allows for new ideas to grow. But without them Kings I can't play the Jester role like I have done in so many LISTSERV communities since 1990.. *"Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears; I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him".*

Comment: IRL Democratic states have elections every 4 years, and heads of state can serve 2 terms. Let's be conservative and assume digital communities only evolve twice as fast. That means after 2 years any Mod, by definition, is a Dictator

Answer (score 14):

Moderator Election is not a scheduled task. It's only available when needed. Currently we have a good track record of moderation tasks and to my knowledge, there is no need for moderator election sometimes soon.

But in our business, things move fast, and we don't know what will happen tomorrow. So the best thing to do is to keep on doing what you are and you'll get your chance eventually.

Comment: A moderator once elected, never goes off unless he/she resigns?

Comment: @AsadRefai It's like electing the Pope. You're in it "for life" :-)

Comment: Ah that's good :). I never knew that. Cheers.

Comment: Where are my Gucci shoes, pointy hat, and bullet proof car?

Comment: @EricAlexander, yeah that shipment must have disappeared

Comment: Well, not always, sometimes they get [asked to step down](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7315/21267)

Comment: its in the mail... :)